# Can I average samples in nested factor within-subject design if samples are from the same condition?

Tags: repeated-measures, mean, sample

This question relates to one of my other questions: [What can cause a "Error() model is singular error" in aov when fitting a repeated measures ANOVA?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/97165/split-plot-with-nested-factors-anova-in-r) .

I have subjects taking an experiment, where I have different `Scenarios` and each `Scenario` contains some number of `Trials`, where subjects can interact with each other between `Trials`, but the `Scenario` stays the same. Can I consider each `Scenario` as a different treatment condition and the trials as samples so I can compute the average on the `Trial`s of each subject for each `Scenario`?