# Lmer model fails to converge

Tags: r, lme4-nlme

My data is described here [What can cause a "Error() model is singular error" in aov when fitting a repeated measures ANOVA?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/97165/what-can-cause-a-error-model-is-singular-error-in-aov-when-fitting-a-repeate)

I am trying to see the effect of an interaction using `lmer` so my base case is:

```
my_null.model <- lmer(value ~ Condition+Scenario+ 
                             (1|Player)+(1|Trial), data = my, REML=FALSE)

my.model <- lmer(value ~ Condition*Scenario+ 
                             (1|Player)+(1|Trial), data = my, REML=FALSE)
```

Running the `anova` gives me significant results, but when I try to account for random slope (`(1+Scenario|Player)`) the model fails with this error:

```
  Warning messages:
 1: In commonArgs(par, fn, control, environment()) :
   maxfun < 10 * length(par)^2 is not recommended.
 2: In optwrap(optimizer, devfun, getStart(start, rho$lower, rho$pp),  :
  convergence code 1 from bobyqa: bobyqa -- maximum number of function evaluations exceeded
 3: In commonArgs(par, fn, control, environment()) :
  maxfun < 10 * length(par)^2 is not recommended.
 4: In optwrap(optimizer, devfun, opt$par, lower = rho$lower, control = control,  :
   convergence code 1 from bobyqa: bobyqa -- maximum number of function evaluations exceeded
 5: In checkConv(attr(opt, "derivs"), opt$par, ctrl = control$checkConv,  :
   Model failed to converge with max|grad| = 36.9306 (tol = 0.002)
 6: In checkConv(attr(opt, "derivs"), opt$par, ctrl = control$checkConv,  :
   Model failed to converge: degenerate  Hessian with 1 negative eigenvalues
```

Alternatively if it fails to converge after a lot of iterations (I set it to `100 000`) and I am getting the same results after `50k` and `100k` it means that it is very close to the actual value, just it does not reach it. So can I report my results like this?

Note that when I set the iterations so high I get only these warnings:

```
 Warning messages:
1: In checkConv(attr(opt, "derivs"), opt$par, ctrl = control$checkConv,  :
 Model failed to converge with max|grad| = 43.4951 (tol = 0.002)
2: In checkConv(attr(opt, "derivs"), opt$par, ctrl = control$checkConv,  :
 Model failed to converge: degenerate  Hessian with 1 negative eigenvalues
```

Answer (score 8):

See [this](https://github.com/lme4/lme4/issues/120) conversation for an alternative method of assessing convergence. Specifically, this comment from Ben Bolker:

> thanks. An even simpler test would be to take a fitted example that gave you convergence warnings and take a look at the results of 
>   `relgrad <- with(fitted_model@optinfo$derivs,solve(Hessian,gradient))`
>   `max(abs(relgrad))`
>   and see if it's reasonably small (e.g. <0.001?)

Alternatively, you could try Bolker's advice [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21344555/convergence-error-for-development-version-of-lme4), which is to try a different optimizer.

Comment: what should one do if max(abs(relgrad)) gives you a value of 2.9239489e-05 ?

Comment: @Jens then that would be really, really small (e-05 means "write 5 zeros and then the numbers you see on the left", with a dot after the first zero). So one would be pretty happy with that value!